# Why is greenkeeper disabled on my project..?

Tags: javascript, git, github, greenkeeper

I added http://greenkeeper.io to https://github.com/billymoon/monsieur which was straight forward, with a pull request being generated, which I merged. I tried to do the same on another project (https://github.com/billymoon/sir) and it is showing disabled. It also is not able to merge the greenkeeper/initilial branch, because there are no changes not in master (as it was merged: https://github.com/billymoon/sir/commit/b5f20afa85c819a1566528d4b54a8d4bb7e5c850).

How can I get greenkeeper initialised in my repo?

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me: delete the remote `greenkeeper/initial` branch:

`git push origin --delete greenkeeper/initial`

Disable your project in the greenkeeper GitHub integration. Save. Re-enable your project, save again.